# Glimpse Does Not Work for my Application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, glimpse

The Glimpse icon never appears on my MVC3 SAAS application. It is an application that has Telerik controls, Jquery and KnockoutJs. Could this be the cause? If I create a new web project and turn on Glimpse, it works.
Any ideas?

I am seeing the following in the Output windows.

A first chance exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in Glimpse.Core.DLL

Comment: What version of Glimpse are you using for both the Glimpse and the Glimpse.MVC3 packages?

Comment: I have the same issue - there is no Glimpse icon. Jquery 1.5.1 (in /assets/scripts/jquery directory... could it be the reason?), Telerik MVC, .Net 4.0, MVC 3.0

Comment: Is there anymore info available about the exception? Stack trace or anything? What version of Glimpse are you using?

Comment: Additional info: I have the same problem and found that the latest version of Glimpse works fine EXCEPT when using the Areas feature of MVC3.  I'll get the "G" icon on main pages of my site, but when I dip into an area, it throws the exception mentioned above.

Comment: Do you have a stack trace for the exception?

Answer (score 2):

Visit this link `http://localhost:####//Glimpse/Config` and press the "Turn Glimpse On" button ;)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else with the same issue I found on my site there was a floating footer div covering the icon. I just needed to hide the div the see the icon.

Comment: For anyone else with this issue, try adding the following to your site.css file: `.glimpse-nowrap {
    z-index: 9999 !important;
}`